# Ошибка при вводе правильного занчения для строковой переменной C++

Tags: c++, строки, локализация

```
string *vsr = new string;
    cin >> *vsr;
    if (*vsr == "Да") { deleteData(&saves, path); delete vsr; goto game; }
    else if (*vsr == "Нет") { delete vsr; goto menu; }
    else { cout << "Непонятная функция" <<n;}
    delete var;
```

Неправильно работающая часть кода здесь - `(*vsr=="Да")`. Когда я ввожу "Да" то срабатывает условие `else` и выводится: "Непонятная функция". При замене русского значения на английское (`setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");` - присутствует) всё работает. Так же в другой похожей части кода -

```
            opa:
        string * vsr = new string;
        cin >> *vsr;
        if (*vsr == "Да") { delete vsr;  goto menu; }
        else if (*vsr == "Нет") { delete vsr; goto opa; }
        else { cout << "Непонятная функция" << n; }
```

Всё работает с русским "Да". В чём тогда заключается проблема?

Неработающая исправленная версия:

```
wstring vsr ;
    wcin >> vsr;
    if (vsr == L"Да") { deleteData(&saves, path); goto game; }
    else if (vsr == L"Нет") {goto menu; }
    else { cout << "Непонятная функция" << n; goto menu; }
```

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в несовпадении кодировки строк и кодировки ввода. Используйте широкие строки (`wstring`) и широкие литералы (то есть `L"Да`" вместо `"Да"`).

Кстати, совершенно непонятно для чего вы создаете строку динамически. Объявляйте просто переменную строки, зачем там указатель?

---

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Действительно, консольные потоки в VC++ совершенно некорректно работают с локалями, так что мой ответ вверху мало что дает. После некоторых экспериментов получилось решить задачу в обход.

```
int main() {
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

  string vsr ;
  cin >> vsr;

  if (vsr == "Да") {
    cout << "Да-да-да!";
  }
  else if (vsr == "Нет") {
    cout << "Найн!";
  }
  else {
    cout << "Ничо не понял...";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

В-общем, еще один аргумент за то, чтобы потоками не пользоваться.

Comment: Всё осталось выполняться точно так же , как и было до этого, с точно таким же выводом.

Comment: @Илья Левицкий, должно нормально работать. Исправленную программу покажите. Только не в комментах, вопрос отредактируйте.